# Move items from one Sitecore version to another version

Tags: sitecore, version, transfer, items, sitecore7.2

Could anyone tell what problems might occur when transferring Sitecore items from an instance having the version 7.2 revision 140... to version 7.2 revision 150...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue when transferring items. The current process of transferring or creating package from one sitecore instance version to another instance has not been changed. For example, I am able to create a sitecore item package from Sitecore 7.2 and install it without any issue on Sitecore 8.1

However, if you want to transfer items from SQL, then you need to check the different table schema but this is not recommended. You can make use of tools like TDS and Razl to do this but they are paid tools.

Comment: I have Razl to use for comparison and synchronization. My concern was related to schema differences between those two. Thank you for you answer.